# Change the rectangular view into quadrilateral view through style - react native

Tags: react-native

Change the rectangular view into quadrilateral view through style

I need to have the quadrilateral background in the view. If it can be done through style, it will be great. Otherwise I've use the image as its background. I dont want to do it however since it wil increase app size as well.

```
<View>
    <Image source={{uri: 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/jaboy/jaboy1706/jaboy170600065/79609763-new-green-light-scenery-background.jpg'}}
      style={{width:200, height: 70 }} />
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10, paddingTop: 25 }}>
      <Text style={styles.red}>just red</Text>
      <Text style={styles.bigBlue}>just bigBlue</Text>
      <Text style={[styles.bigBlue, styles.red]}>bigBlue, then red</Text>
      <Text style={[styles.red, styles.bigBlue]}>red, then bigBlue</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

how it looks now

[image]

how I want it to look like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using 2 views.

```
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftWidth: 200,
        borderTopWidth: 30,
        borderLeftColor: 'red',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      }}
    />
    <View style={{ height: 70, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Text>A</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```